# Prevent SettingsFlyout from reopening settings menu on dismiss

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

In Windows 8.1 using `SettingsFlyout` from the SDK, is there a way to prevent the settings menu reappearing on dismiss?

To give a use case, the pane in question is a user sign out pane, accessible via. the charms menu however I also want to open it when the user taps their thumbnail - but it then makes no sense to reopen the charms menu!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your call to show the pane, use `ShowIndependent()` instead of `Show()`.  The `Show()` method should be used when launched from the Settings charm itself to keep the flow.

Comment: Thanks Tim! I was searching for a prevent dismiss or dismiss mode property, not a method :(